# why Logo Facebook is showed in my facebook app?

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

```
string dialog_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" + app_id + "&redirect_uri=" + Server.UrlEncode(my_url) + "&scope=" + permission;
                Response.Redirect(dialog_url);
```

I use this code to redirect user to (ask permission)'s page.
Logo Facebook is showed in my facebook app. And users is not redirected. 
User have to click the logo to go to that page.

ps. my_url = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/";

Thank you,
Jumbo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your page embedded in a frame? For security reasons, Facebook don't allow you to load any of the permissions dialogs in an iframe or frameset. You will need to get javascript to load the page in the root window, or try opening in a new pop-up window.